# Override entire magento layout from observer

Tags: magento, layout, magento-1.7

## Problem Space

I'm trying to use an observer in magento to completely replace the entire layout for a given request based on a parameter in the request.

The issue I'm facing is that Magento is still trying to load a different root block template than the one I specified in my Observer (specifically "frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml" for product pages which is the default root block template used by the template configured in the design tab of the backend).  Because it isn't using the layout I specified, it dies in PHP trying to load templates that don't exist in the theme.

Any guidance is appreciated.

*Note: I am not using a CMS page to test this concept since they load their own templates as specified in the backend.  I created a test product and am using its product page.  The test is made by requesting the following URL: `http://mymagentosite.com/test-product?ajax=1`*

### Possible Issues

- I may not be listening to the right event to completely replace the layout.  Documentation is sparse so I guessed based on other Stack Overflow responses to layout questions.
- Folder structure of layout elements seems like voodoo to me since I find disparate opinions on the subject (e.g. page.xml vs. local.xml)

### Implementation

I've created a module with an observer and a very minimal layout as follows:

#### Module Folder Structure

```
app
├── code
│   └── local
│       └── MyCompany
│           └── MyModule
│               ├── etc
│               │   └── config.xml
│               └── Model
│                   └── Observer.php
├── design
│   └── frontend
│       └── myTheme
│           └── default
│               ├── layout
│               │   └── local.xml
│               └── template
│                   └── test.phtml
└── etc
    └── modules
        └── MyCompany_MyModule.xml
```

#### config.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0.0</version>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
                <observers>
                    <myCompany_myModule_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>changeRequestLayout</method>
                    </myCompany_myModule_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

#### Observer.php

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php

class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function changeRequestLayout($observer)
    {
        if ($observer->getAction()->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')->setPackageName('myTheme')->setTheme('default');
        }
    }
}
```

### local.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0.0">
    <default>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="test.phtml" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

#### test.phtml

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing, testing...1...2...3...</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color:#f00;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test of the Magento layout system.  This is only a test.  If this were not a test, real content would follow.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

#### MyCompany_MyModule.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: I'd start with "is your observer being called".  Without knowing that there's too many different directions to take this question.

Comment: Yes.  It's being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Real Problem

Magento's layered XML layout system is the source of the confusion in accomplishing what should be a trivial use case.

Because the base/default layout XML is combined with whatever layout I specify, I must not only override the root layout but also all of the other derived layouts defined in the base/default/page.xml.  This is not practical as Magento defines a large number of customized layouts based on the type of page the client is browsing.

## My Solution

The cleanest solution is to create symbolic links in the template/page directory to point to my test.phtml file for all of the following layouts.  This guarantees that Magento will only use *my* layout template.

Note: you must enable template symlinks for this to work (in the admin backend, navigate to System>Configuration>Advanced>Developer, expand "Template Settings" and set "Allow Symlinks" to "Yes").

### Files Linked to test.phtml

- 1column.phtml
- 2columns-left.phtml
- 2columns-right.phtml
- 3columns.phtml
- empty.phtml
- popup.phtml
- print.phtml
- redirect.phtml

Comment: your solution is not good. of course you can return any page you want and totally skip the base  layout by changing the root template - if you do it correctly. this is most often used when dealing with ajax output. another solution would be  to just fetch a block and return its html via response from within controller action. your local.xml is simply wrong you should use action method="setTemplate" to change the root template. as in your root template no childhtml for content header footer and so on is called it will be never rendered...long story short: your solution is not a proper solution

Comment: @MischaLeiss Briefly: yes, this is for AJAX.  No, referencing the root and only changing the template is _NOT_ what I need.  The point of this entire question is to find out how to correctly replace/bypass the entire layout.  If you have a specific code example of how to change the root template correctly, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution i built that definitely does the job of switching the design package/theme via `controller_front_init_before` event.

Of course you could check some request params inside `changeConfigNode()` method with 
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('switch')` and just append the request param `switch/1` to trigger the changes.

```
   <global>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_before>
            <observers>
                <cartware_change_the_node>
                     <class>cartware_guest2customer/observer</class>
                     <method>changeConfigNode</method>
                </cartware_change_the_node>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_before>               
    </events>
   </global>
```

And the observer method:

```
public function changeConfigNode(){

    /** left for testing
    Mage::log( Mage::app()->getConfig()->getXmlString());
            **/

    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('stores/default/design/package/name', 'enterprise');
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('stores/default/design/package/theme', 'enterprise');
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('stores/default/design/package/default_theme', 'enterprise');
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('stores/default/design/theme/default', 'enterprise');
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('stores/default/design/theme/layout', 'enterprise');
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('stores/default/design/theme/template', 'enterprise');



}
```

Its without additional checks but it might help you! Good luck!

Comment: I added an echo statement to Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView to display which view file it's trying to load.  I played around with your suggestion and my original logic and determined the problem is not in the logic but in my template (I tried my original approach and successfully switched to another template I previously installed).  For some reason I do not understand, when I try to switch to my minimal template it attempts to load frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml which is not part of my theme.

Comment: maybe you have no 2columns-right template in your theme thus the fallback to base/default.

Comment: You are correct, I don't have a 2columns-right template.  The reason being that I don't want it or any other built-in template to be used by my website.  I want Magento to use _my_ template which does not reference 2columns-right in any way shape or form (at least, not that I can see).  This is why I'm looking for a way to override the _entire_ layout.

Comment: 2-columns-right is used as a "root" template. I guess its still in use! You need to `reference the root` block via layout.xml and `setTemplate` to another than `2-columns-right.phtml`

Comment: So...how would that differ from what local.xml is doing?

Comment: @Coren:  Well you can change the used layout on the fly by checking/using some request values. It could be built into developer toolbars...and so on...

Comment: What I meant by "...how would that differ..." is how would I reference the root block to set the template differently than I'm already doing in local.xml?  Specifically, what would the code look like?

Comment: Your local.xml is wrong i guess. You just add a block with name root. you need to reference the root block and do action method='setTemplate' ....

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that by referencing the root block as you suggest, I would update the existing root block and only change the template whereas by specifying a root block in my layout, I completely replace the root block (which is what I'm trying to do).